# How to pass array and hash via JQuery post?

Tags: jquery, post, parameters

Does this work:

```
$.post("http://localhost:3000/api/products",
       "products[][id]=1&products[][any]=2&products[][id]=3&products[][any]=4")
    .always(function(data) {
        console.log(data.responseText);
    });
```

The return is:

```
{:message=>[#<Hashie::Mash any=2 id=1>, #<Hashie::Mash any=4 id=3>]}
```

But, in the parameter, how do I do to use variable (hash or array) instead of a string, in a way that return the same effect?

I can use

```
$.post("http://localhost:3000/api/products",
       {'products[]': { id: 1, any: 2 }}
    .always(function(data) {
    ...
```

to send a single product, but how to send multiple?

Comment: Why are you trying to manually compile the data string? What server language are you using that generates that message?

Comment: It's just to illustrate what I want to do: send two hash. The server is using Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Read the `$.ajax` api docs. Really not clear what you are asking. Manually creating strings is not the norm, passing objects or using `serialize()` on a form is far more conventional

Comment: I edited the question. That's better?

Comment: That object is only restricted in size by any server restrictions (if any) that may exist for post parameter limits